# Python Log error 'NonType'

Tags: python, types, where-clause

I' m new to python and would like to ask the following:
I get this error message

> bad operand type for unary ~: 'NoneType'

when I'm running a very simple data step as:

```
df['new_FLAG'] = np.where(~(df.var2.str.contains('Test|Random|Hypo|Sample',case = False)) & 
   df.var3.isin(['CLIENT_CURRENT', 'MODEL_CURRENT', 'HYPOTHETICAL']) &
   (df.var1> 4) & (df.var1< 31)
                                 ,'Y','N')
```

My data frame is like this:

```
    var1    var2    var3
0   17  AMPF PCA 5.9.18 MODEL_CURRENT
1   17  AMPF PCA 5.9.18 MODEL_CURRENT
2   17  AMPF PCA 5.9.18 MODEL_CURRENT
3   17  AMPF PCA 5.9.18 MODEL_CURRENT
4   17  AMPF PCA 5.9.18 MODEL_CURRENT
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have non-string types in your series. Try setting `na=False` in `pd.Series.str.contains` to correct this. The negative of `None` is not defined, which is what your error is indicating.

Here's a minimal example:

```
s = pd.Series(['Testing', 'AnotherSTring', 2.5, 'Something Else', np.nan, 'Sampler'])

res1 = s.str.contains('Test|Random|Hypo|Sample', case=False)

# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2      NaN
# 3    False
# 4      NaN
# 5     True
# dtype: object

res2 = s.str.contains('Test|Random|Hypo|Sample', case=False, na=False)

# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3    False
# 4    False
# 5     True
# dtype: bool
```

Comment: @ChrissieM., Excellent, please do accept (green tick on left) if this resolves your issue.